# When building/compiling flip fluids, I just get a bunch of error s and a weird, partial build

Tags: add-on, fluid-simulation

Like the title states, when building flip fluid I get a partial build that can be installed as an add on into blender, but when I try to bake a sim it tells me that it cant find "libblpyfluid.dll" and when I look for any type of fluid file, its missing. Hopefully someone can help, thanks! Here's what I get when building/compiling (I put it in a text file so its much easier to read):
https://drive.google.com/open?id=120t0U87DNAMqeXcSUOBgGHiLs-p6Pjxa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is nai be a pre release of its latest version and you will have to complete it yourself. I know that can be tricky but there are many blogs which can help you complete it yourself if you are able to find one which suits you and is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Go the Addons folder and edit `pyfluid/pyfluid.py`.

Change:

```
if system == "Windows":
libname = "libblpyfluid.dll"
```

To:

```
if system == "Windows":
libname = "blpyfluid.dll"
```